# Flutter: Slider button is not rebuilding after set state

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

I am using this plugin `slider_button 2.0.0` https://pub.dev/packages/slider_button
Here I have created the widget and I need this slider button to appear always.

This slider button is not rebuilding again after I am doing some action, based on my bloc state management condition, I am rebuilding the entire screen, ideally it should rebuild whenever I am calling setState() function. But it is not happening.

Below is my code for slider button,

Main Screen Code:

```
return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBarWidget(),
   body: Container(
     child: SliderButtonWidget(),
   ),
);
```

Below is my SliderButtonWidget code:

```
return SliderButton(
          action: () {
            setState(() {
              
            });
          },
          label: Text('Swipe to proceed'),
          alignLabel: Alignment(0, 0),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
          buttonColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.8),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
          highlightedColor: Colors.white,
          baseColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          height: AppSizeConstants.SIZE_60,
        );
```

**I have this code as a widget and calling as a function from my main screen, while debugging the breakpoint is hitting to the `return` statement, but widget is not building.**

Can someone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean it's not rebuilding? It's not like a rebuild would be visible since there are no variables involved. But also seeing that you call a method called `_navigateToHomeScreen()` I assume you will go to a new page where of course this button won't be there. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Ivo , I have editted the above snippets, I am not navigating to the new screen now, but   if I slide the button for the first time, My slider button got dismissed(disappeared), Since I have given the action to do `setState()`, it should appear again ryt? but I am not getting the slider button again.